# Trouble using SetActive to disable and enable an object?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a speed boost `GameObject` (sphere object) that has a collider with trigger **on** and then a simple SpeedBoost script attached to it also.

When my player collides with the speed boost sphere, the object temporarily deactivates but is not destroyed and then my player gets a brief speed boost via a coroutine. After a set amount of time, I end the speed boost and reactivate the object, where the whole process then repeats.

But sometimes the object reactivates instantly and when it happens and I enter its trigger, I don't get any speed boost and the object doesn't deactivate.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.tag == "Player")
    {
        StartCoroutine(RespawnSpeedBoost());
    }
}

IEnumerator RespawnSpeedBoost()
{
    movement.walkSpeed = boostedWalkSpeed;
    movement.sprintSpeed = boostedSprintSpeed;
    speedBoost.SetActive(false);        
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
    speedBoost.SetActive(true);
    movement.walkSpeed = walkSpeed;
    movement.sprintSpeed = sprintSpeed;
}
```

Comment: Two potential issues. You should start the coroutine immediately in `OnTriggerEnter` instead of setting a variable and hoping the next Update call does it. You should also have some protection to keep the coroutine from running more than once. Right now every Update for the 3 seconds the coroutine waits will start another coroutine because `isBoosted` remains true for all that time. Starting it inside `OnTriggerEnter` may help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the Update callback which is called based on your framerate multiple times a second, so what most likely happens is.

- you enter the trigger and set the variable
- for 3 seconds the coroutine is started like 30 times per second meaning now 90 coroutines are running
- after 3 seconds the first coroutine started will set isBoosted=false and reactivate the trigger
- you hit the trigger again during the next 3 seconds and each few milliseconds the other coroutines which are still running are finishing and are reactivating your trigger and resetting the isBoosted variable

What you should do is probably something like starting the coroutine once when the trigger is hit and set all necessary parameters. After three seconds the coroutine will finish and reset everything.

So in this case you don't need the Update callback at all.

Comment: I've actually tried many solutions but none have worked. I tried taking the `coroutine` outside of `Update`, I've tried completely removing `Update` all together and only having one `coroutine` to handle the speed boost but every result has been the same.

Comment: You should update your question with what you have tried and try integrating my answer and I can check where the issue is. What I have written is clearly the issue with your current code. Without seeing the improved version I can not help.

Comment: I've just updated my code. Everything works great (the SetActive turning false and true), but now **only** the sprint speed gets boosted and the walk speed remains untouched which is weird, so only one of the speeds is getting boosted, and not both (walk & sprint).

Comment: Code looks fine now from what is shown, the issue you are having now is related to some other part. You can check what the actual values are that you are setting in the coroutine maybe your boostedWalkSpeed is not what you are expecting or something else is changing it somewhere else. If your initial issue is fixed select mark the answer. If you have another issue try to give more information in another question.